# How to make objects move relative to background, not browser window?

Tags: html, css

I have tried using CSS to set the position of the background and the objects to all possible types (fixed, relative, absolute).  I have also adjusted the width, min-width of the background image.

[The Test Page](http://test.thebkk.net)

CSS:

- Background:

  ```
  /* BG Image Style */
  .bg {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%
   }
  ```
- Player

  ```
  /* Player Style */
  #player {
   position: absolute;
   width: 680px;
   top: 60px;
   left: 380px;
   border: outset 5px white;
   }
  ```
- Menu

  ```
  /* Nav Menu */
  ul#menu {
   position: absolute;
   top: 175px; 
   left: 68px;
   padding: 0; 
   list-style: none;
   clear: both;     
   }
  ```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>BKK Testing Zone</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<img class="bg" src="http://thebkk.net/Images/BVF-Template-Complete.png"/>

<div id="player">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://thebkk.net/Scripts/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'>      
</script> 

<div id='mediaspace'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
 jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
  'flashplayer': 'http://thebkk.net/Scripts/jwplayer/player.swf',
  'playlistfile': 'http://www.thebkk.net/test/playlist.xml',
  'backcolor': '000000',
  'frontcolor': '00FFFF',
  'lightcolor': '33FF33',
  'playlist': 'right',
  'controlbar': 'bottom',
  'width': '680',
  'height': '360',
  });
</script>
</div>

<ul id="menu">
<li class="home"><a href="http://thebkk.net"></a></li>
<li class="rules"><a href=""></a></li>
<li class="forums"><a href="http://forum.thebkk.net"></a></li>
<li class="links"><a href="" alt="Links"></a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!  I searched around, and there were parts of what I wanted to do, but can't seem to find exactly what it is I want.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by move relatively to the background?

Comment: What *is* it that you want? You haven't told us what's wrong with your page, or what you're trying to accomplish. All you've done is linked to a page that appears to be working just fine. Your question *doesn't contain a question*, and so there is nothing here for us to answer.

Comment: Apologies, had so much forgot to add that back to the top.  I want the entire page to scale to the browser window, however, this means I want the elements within the page to resize to the background, so that their positions do not change.  I want the one size that looks right to fit all windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read up on "Responsive Web".  There's a lot of ideas in there in terms of making fluid grids that might help in what you're doing.

Regardless, I don't know if you're going to get what you're looking to do to work perfectly with CSS alone.  You'll probably have to work with some JavaScript as well.

I would start over and try doing something like this for basic HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="media"></div>

        <div class="menu"></div>

        <img src="background.png" />
    </div>
</body>
```

I would put things in a container div just because I don't like working directly off the body element for CSS.  It's a little more self contained modules.

As for CSS, you will make your background image like you have.

Your menu will then need to images put into the list items (LI) with the IMG tag.  Those IMG will need a width:100% style.

Right now, you're using the menu images as backgrounds, which won't be fluid very well, so just like you did with the main background image, you need to do with your menu.

You then need to set the menu container width to be a % of the larger container (ie. the background image).

To get this % you need to divide the width of the area you want the menu to fit in by the total container width.

Your background image looks like it's 1280px.  The total width of the "window" is like 214px.

This would mean the width of the menu should be:

214px / 1280px = 0.1671875 * 100% = 16.71875%

You then need to place the menu container properly using the same CSS as you where using but use % instead of pixels because this will allow the positioning to move with the browser size.

The upper left corner of that background "window" looks like it starts 20px in from the left and 263px down from the top.

20px / 1280px = 0.015625 * 100% = 1.5625%

```
left: 1.5625%
```

263px / 960px = 0.27395833333333333 * 100% = 27.39583333333%

```
top: 27.39583333333%;
```

Now, the menu container should have a proportional width compared to the background image (which is what you're trying to line the menu up with), meaning it should sort of expand or contract with the background image.

And remember the menu HTML needs to be like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="..." alt="" /></li>
    [...]
</ul>
```

with CSS:

```
#menu li img{ 
    width:100%; 
}
```

I'm not really sure this will work but it might get you going in the right direction.  Regardless, I don't see the result of this being very good.

This might be a case where you're better off making a full Flash website (as much as I don't like using Flash).

I hope that helps!

Cheers!

-- UPDATE --

I put together a little proof-of-concept.  I only tested it in Chrome and the latest FF.  As I expected, you can get it to work but you're going to run into support issues.

Anyway, here's a background image I made with basically 2 target areas (boxes).  It's similar to original one.

background image (1000x750.  I started with 1024x768 or iPad dimensions and made it 1000px wide for easy percentages)

http://tinypic.com/r/11r9edw/5

menu image 1

http://tinypic.com/r/2s7ucmg/5

menu image 4 (i'll skip uploading all the menu images for sake of brevity)

http://tinypic.com/r/2nlv42x/5

The CSS (percentages are sloppy, but it's only a proof-of-concept)

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#F0F; 
}
.bg-img{
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:1; 
}
.menu{
    position:absolute; 
    width:15%; 
    height:33%;
    top:33%; 
    left:10%; 
    border:1px dashed red; 
    z-index:10; 
}
.menu ul{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.menu li img{ 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.menu li{ 
    position:relative; 
    height:24.5%;
}

.media{
    position:absolute; 
    width:43%; 
    height:15%; 
    top:16%; 
    left:31%; 
    background:#9CC;
    z-index:10; 
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="bg-img" src="bg.png" alt="" />

    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="menu1.png" alt="Menu 1" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="menu1.png" alt="Menu 2" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="menu4.png" alt="Menu 3" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="menu4.png" alt="Menu 4" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="media"></div>

</div>
```

I more or less just used position:absolute to "float" everything as a ratio/percentage of the background image, which is stretched to 100% width/height of the browser.

Defined heights/widths are necessary (and setting margins/padding to zero to reset browser defaults).

Chrome seemed to work well.  FF seemed to have an issue with height:100%.  It's possible it could be cleaned up some more, but that should be a start to get what you're looking to do with CSS.

But like I said, this kind of thing isn't well handled in CSS, even with CSS3 this kind of design will cause a lot of headaches for backwards compatibility.

HTML 5 is here and that's not going to be a magic bullet either.  This design concept is very vector based and Flash is perfect for that kind of thing.

Hope this helps! =)

Comment: With HTML5 coming, was trying to avoid flash haha.  What kind of Java Script or JQuery options do I have?  Is there a script that could look at my page as an "image" essentially, then re-size that?  Going to work with what you have posted, will get back if anything works out.  Thanks for all the info!!

Comment: Hehe, HTML5 is here my friend.  Support is pretty good to start using a lot of it and there's some nice JS tools to get older browsers up-to-speed.  There's no plugin that I'm aware of to get all elements to re-size proportionally but one could probably be made.  But I would shudder to think of the performance that would have on the site. =)  If I have some time later today, I'll see if I can try to mock-up a test case of what I mentioned above. =)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot combine a relatively sized background with elements that are of fixed size and with fixed margins, and expect the fixed elements to "follow" the background when you resize the window.

My suggestion would be that you use a fixed size background as well, that is the only way to get the other elements (menu etc.) to end up at its expected spot.

Also, when creating a background, you should really use the CSS background property, instead of using an image like you do.

This:

```
<img class="bg" src="http://thebkk.net/Images/BVF-Template-Complete.png">
```

Should probably be this:

```
body { background: url('http://thebkk.net/Images/BVF-Template-Complete.png') no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Ok so this fixes the positioning of my menu and video player, now how do I make it all re-size properly for different window sizes?

Comment: @tBoat I'd say you don't. I would make it a fixed size no matter the window size, and perhaps just put it vertically and horizontally aligned on the page. It would be really tough to make it work with relative sizes.

Comment: Ok, well if I position it using margin's in the CSS, ie. Towards the middle, I then add a `background: black url(myimageurl) no-repeat;` which gives me black around it, but there is a line along the edge of the background image...taking away margin or padding does nothing.